# Why JAXB (jaxb2-maven-plugin) skips this attribute?

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

`jaxb2-maven-plugin 1.3`  skips an attribute from an object. I cannot modify the `XSD`. In the `XSD` (fragment):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="classA" type="classA" substitutionGroup="classSubA"/>

    <xs:complexType name="complexClassA" mixed="true">

    <xs:attribute name="attA">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <moProperty value="classA:attA"/>
                <label value="Attribute A" default="true"/>
                <externAccess value="readWrite"/>
            <description value="NO COMMENTS"/>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="off"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="on"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>

<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:unsignedInt">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <moProperty value="myClassB:id"/>
            <label value="Id" default="true"/>
            <externAccess value="readWrite"/>
            <description value="NO COMMENTS"/>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:attribute>
</xs:schema>
```

The Resulting `Java Object` (fragment):

```
public class ComplexClassA {
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "unsignedInt")
    protected Long id;
}
```

Why it is not generating the      `attA` member?

Might it be cause the inline enumeration?

Thank you.

Udo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going to

org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2
   maven-jaxb2-plugin

Everything is working fine.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a complete XML schema that demonstrates the problem?  Below the line is what I have tried and everything appears to work as expected.

---

When I run XJC on the following XML schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Foo" xmlns="http://www.example.org/Foo" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:complexType name="complexClassA" mixed="true">

        <xs:attribute name="attA">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <moProperty value="classA:attA"/>
                    <label value="Attribute A" default="true"/>
                    <externAccess value="readWrite"/>
                    <description value="NO COMMENTS"/>
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="off"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="on"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>

        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:unsignedInt">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <moProperty value="myClassB:id"/>
                    <label value="Id" default="true"/>
                    <externAccess value="readWrite"/>
                    <description value="NO COMMENTS"/>
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>

    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

I get the following class as expected:

```
package org.example.foo;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "complexClassA", propOrder = {
    "content"
})
public class ComplexClassA {

    @XmlValue
    protected String content;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String attA;
    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "unsignedInt")
    protected Long id;

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String value) {
        this.content = value;
    }

    public String getAttA() {
        return attA;
    }

    public void setAttA(String value) {
        this.attA = value;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long value) {
        this.id = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: What about the inline enum? Where it is? Sorry but I can't disclose the XSD. I will add a more meaningful example tomorrow when I'll be in the office. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

What JAXB version are you using? The inline Enumeration should be turned into an Java enum correctly.

You could try to define the simpleType outside the Attribute definition, that would help probably.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I cannot modify the file.